# Selecting 2 balls from different boxes

Tags: combinatorics

We are given $N$ boxes and the number of balls in each box. Let the number of balls in boxes be $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_N$. All the balls in the same box are identical.

Find the number of ways of selecting 2 balls from $N$ boxes such that both of the balls should not be selected from the same box.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck on the problem?  You'll find that people here are much quicker to help if you show us what you've already thought about and where you are getting stuck; that way, we know exactly where you're at and what you need help with.

Comment: Also: does the order in which the balls are chosen matter?

Comment: The order does not matter. We just have to find no. of ways such that each ball be chosen from a different box.

Comment: My approach was like this: I know that I can choose a ball from a box of n balls in n ways. So, if I choose first ball from box1 and second ball from box2, I can do it in p1*p2 no. of ways. Similarly this can be done for every pair of boxes. Hence the answer should be the sum of products of the no. of balls in each box taken two at a time. But I don't know if it is the correct approach, so I asked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hint

For the understanding of the problem, the numbers $p_i$ are irrelevant at first.
Try to draw a decision tree and treat the $p_i$ as a measure of probability of chosing a ball from box $i$ - the rest should become clear then.

Also, please specify what you mean by "identical".

Comment: By identical, I mean that the balls in the same box are of equal size and same color. I also want to know what will be the answer if the balls in a box are not identical.

Comment: Now I understand.
Picking the first Ball is without restrictions. The number of possibilities therefor is
$$p = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i$$
For the second one, assuming the first was from box $j$, we have
$$p' = \sum_{\stackrel{i=1}{i\neq j}}^N p_i$$
So we have:
$$P = \sum_{j=1}^N \left ( p_j \cdot \sum_{\stackrel{i=1}{i\neq j}}^N p_i \right )$$
I'll leave simplification to you.

Comment: So the answer should be the sum of p and p` with j (the box from which first ball is chosen) running from 1 to N ?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I'm happy to help ;-) I suggest to mark it as solved, so others know, the question is dealt with, unless there is still something unclear?

Comment: Everything is clear now. Marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the problem needs interpretation. We will assume that balls in different boxes are of different colours, and that each box has at least one ball.

Then the number of ways is just the number of ways to select $2$ boxes from $N$.